# Multiple Google visualization queries for single visualization

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, google-query-language

link to jsfiddle example -- https://jsfiddle.net/ad4j2fmp/

I am trying to perform multiple queries to a google spreadsheet to get results for a single visualization. Is there a way to perform multiple queries for a single visualization + store the results as arrays that I can manipulate(splice). Then after manipulation be able to reference those arrays for

```
    data.addRows([array1,array2,array3]);
```

the "data" in data.addRows being referenced is the data relating to hierarchy- which is required for the treemap.(ex: Earth --> Europe --> UK)

The additional queries I've tried to make are for information relating to (in this example: countries)

I've tried making multiple queries for a single visualization but I've been unsuccessful (my knowledge of javascript is basic)

1. How to perform multiple Google Visualization Queries and use them for a single visualization
2. How to convert Google Visualization Query results into manipulatable arrays that --> (after manipulation of results) --> can then feed into data.addRows();